# Get/Refresh TFS OAuth token failed with invalid_grant

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am receiving this error on my Azure website, it's only recently started happening!

It's hooked up to Visual Studio Online / TF Service, so it gets deployed from there.

Why could this be happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try disconnect TFS  in Web site in Azure manage (`Disconnect from Visual Studio Online`), if you can't do it because Azure throws you a message like "Could not disconnect TFS from the Windows Azure cloud service 'UAT'" or similar, you can go to `Control Panel` in TFS Administration and select `Services Section`, and disconnect Azure service, now `Disconnect from Visual Studio Online` in Azure.

Finally, you reconnect with a source control and select Visual Studio in TFS Administration.

Comment: Yes - this works, but I've observed that the same issue keeps happening?  Any workarounds to fix or is this an Azure support issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error show up when I logged into the Azure Management Console.  However, when I disconnected the web site from Visual Studio Online, it did it successfully.  I then reconnected it to Visual Studio Online and I no longer get the error.

It appears that they have fixed the issue with disconnecting so the built in tools should now work without requiring a work-around.